# Automated FTP to Windows servers

Tags: windows, ftp

I need to set up some sort of infrastructure to automatically FTP some files from one remote server to another. The FTP transaction will occur on a scheduled basis. Both these servers are Windows boxes and the location of the files that need to be FTP'ed will depend on the current date (the folder they sit in will be named the current day's date).

I would really hate to have to write something like that from scratch, so are there tools/utilities/the likes out there?

Comment: Seems to be a nice question for serverfault not SO.

Answer (score 3):

Windows command line `ftp` will read input from a text file. For example:

```
ftp -ni < ftpscript.txt
```

Where these options are used:

- `-n` - Suppresses auto-login upon initial connection.
- `-i` - Turns off interactive prompting during multiple file transfers.

The `ftpscript.txt` would look something like this:

```
open ftp.mycompany.com
user someuser password
binary
get /somedir/myfile.dat
```

It should be reasonably straightforward to write a script that outputs an FTP script containing the correct file name.

Comment: Using this method, is there anyway to get it to grab the newest file? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You would think that this would be an easy task. It isn't.

The best tool I've found is SyncBack and I think there is a free/lite version available.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a Windows environment consider using PowerShell and the System.Net.WebClient .NET Framework class like [this post](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/17000-using-powershell-automate-ftp-transfers.html). This is a download example, but the WebClient object also provides an UploadFile method.